# Temporarily use different URL

Tags: seo, redirects, url, homepage

Client asked me to temporarily replace homepage for product list, until he decides what should be on the homepage (that's not my business :))

I would like to know, how big impact it will have on the SEO ranking if I just use URL: `www.example.com` for product list and after several months it changes to homepage and product list will move to other URL (`www.example.com/product/list`)

I think it's not good idea to do it this way. I would rather redirect every request that lands on `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/product/list` . Is this solution more SEO friendly? Or do you have another ideas?

Comment: Can you not load all data of product list on home page? Because you are thinking about URL redirection and that could affect SEO.

Comment: I can do that.. But would not it be worse when product list after few months suddenly dissapear from that URL (www.example.bar - its content will completely change) and reappear on another?

Comment: I agree with your but to save it from SEO negative effect , this is only way I think you can apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a `302 - temporary redirect`. Example in PHP:

```
header("Location: /product/list", true, 302); // temporal redirect
```

The browsers requests the `/home` url, gets `status 302, new url: /example` back from the server. Your browser now says "Oh ok, I'll now open `/example` for now".

Bots understand the redirect; the `302` makes them understand this is temporary. A `301 - status` redirect would've said "The requested url is no longer used, use `/example` from now on". In terms of SEO this means your homepage won't be forgotten, just checked less often (which isn't a problem as it contains nothing valuable).

---

Alternatively, make a hybrid page. Make a generic homepage with some generic welcome text and some simple explanation about the company, slam a productlist beneath/nextto that and add "Quick pick:" above, making it seem like this is the way it should work.

Technically not a big difference, but for users it is; you've just skipped the unexplainable redirect (for them it is; they wanted home). In SEO terms this is also preferred, a homepage can create some valuable content you might need, especially for a product site.

This also gives you a start on what to do on the homepage. Installing a redirect will only be forgotten.

Comment: Yes, I think I would go for this approach, rather than temporarily showing the "product list" on the homepage URL. Then, when you have content for the homepage you simply remove the redirect.

Comment: Pretty well explained. Especially the "human behaviour" of browsers and bots.

Comment: `s/temporal/temporary/`

Comment: I think the key thing, which isn't explicit here, is how does this method affect/maintain SEO, as opposed to others?

Comment: Added a tiny bit about that :)